# Algorithm To be used for communications and generating keys?

Tags: php, cryptography

I want to send some data to the client server as they will be using our services. There will be some communication about the player details. Which encryption should be used and how to generate the key for that encryption algorithm. Our code is in php.

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [OpenSSL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php) functions. This is how you generate a new public/private key pair:

```
$res = openssl_pkey_new();

openssl_pkey_export($res, $privatekey); // Get private key

$publickey = openssl_pkey_get_details($res); // Get public key
$publickey = $publickey["key"];
```

Store the private key on server and send the public key to clients, then on server:

```
openssl_private_encrypt( $data, $encrypted, $privatekey );
```

in client:

```
openssl_public_decrypt( $encrypted, $data, $publickey );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to encrypt the data send from the client to your server or vice-versa, you should use SSL. You can get a cheap certificate for your website. If you don't have a certificate the encryption will still work but people visititng the website will see a warning regarding the invalid certificate.

Paying for a certificate will be around $10 (based on a Dutch company which sells them).

Comment: How about using the SHA1 Algorithm where there will be no decryption. But how to generate its key ??

Comment: Im not sure what your question is here, do you want to generate a SHA1 key?

Comment: SHA1 is used for coputing a hash value, not for encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a look at [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/), which includes an RSA implementation